# Is it possible to get a len() of a TextInput field in Discord.py 2.0?

Tags: python, discord.py

My bot has an Introduction feature using modals with two TextInputs, one for your introduction and the other to link to something related to your work, like a Discord server, art comissions, etc. But I don't want it to be required to fill, so I need to have an algorithm to detect if the user inputted something in the links' TextInput while filling the modal to decide whether or not to send an embed with both TextInputs or only the one with an introduction. Problem is, the only way I could think of for doing this was using the len() function on the TextInput but when I try to print out that value I only receive an output of "1" even though I typed way more than a single character. Here's the relevant code:

```
async def on_submit(self, interaction: discord.Interaction):
        form = discord.Embed(
            title=None,
            description= f"{self.apresentacoes}\n\n**Encontre meu trabalho aqui:**\n{self.links}", 
            color=3092790)
        form.set_author(name = interaction.user, icon_url=interaction.user.avatar)
        print(len({self.links})) 
       
        await interaction.response.send_message(content="Your introduction has been sent to the #introductions text channel. Check it out!", ephemeral=True)
        

        channel = bot.get_channel(canal_introducao)
        await channel.send(embed=form)
```

Comment: `{self.links}` is a set with one element, so you will always get 1.

Answer (score 0):

Don't to `len({self.links})`, do `len(self.links)`.

Comment: It now gives me:

TypeError: object of type 'TextInput' has no len()